# Is there any API to write an app which can replace the built-in trackpad function for Samsung Dex mode

Tags: android, mouse, trackpad, samsung-dex

Is there any API to write an app which can replace the built-in trackpad function for Samsung Dex mode.

I have been searching about it but cannot find out any API to show a mouse cursor and control it on Dex mode without connecting external mouse or trackpad devices.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: When you enter Dex mode, the device becomes a touchpad. To my knowledge that feature is built-in to the Samsung ROM/Samsung Dex mode. You may want to explain in detail you use case for replacing the touchpad if it isn't just 'I want a different look' or 'I want to add features'.